# Should votes on comments be incorporated into the reputation of the commentator?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, badges, up-votes

The website does has the facility to upvote & flag comments & considers it to be an achievement to create a comment which has more than 5 upvotes - which shows that comments are taken seriously here. Single-sentence & link only answers can also be given in the form of comments. In this view, I question the logic behind not incorporating comment reputation into the overall reputation of the user.

Comment: I recommend going through the article on [Comments](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) once.

Comment: Related: [Should comment upvotes reward reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82685/should-comment-upvotes-reward-reputation)